# How can I create a new column to identify the sequence between Zero Values

Tags: sequence, zero

I would like to create a new column in order to figure it out how many different sequences I have when I find the Zero value until the next Zero value, with 1’s values between then.

**I am using R to develop such code:**

I have two Scenarios: I have the **Conversion Column** and I'd like to create the **New Column**

**First Scenario (when my Conversions Column starts with 1):**

| Conversions | New Column (The Sequence) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |

**Second Scenario (when my Conversions Column starts with 0)**

| Conversions | New Column (The Sequence) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

dt1 <- tibble(
  conversion = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  sequence = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  id = 1:17
)

dt2 <- tibble(
  conversion = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  sequence = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
  id = 1:17
)

build_seq <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      new_col = ifelse((conversion - lag(conversion, 1)) == -1, id, NA),
      new_col = as.numeric(as.factor(new_col))
    ) %>%
    tidyr::fill(new_col, .direction = "down") %>%
    mutate(
      new_col = ifelse(is.na(new_col), 1, new_col + 1)
    )
}

new_dt1 <- build_seq(dt1)
new_dt2 <- build_seq(dt2)
  
all(new_dt1$new_col == new_dt1$sequence)
all(new_dt2$new_col == new_dt2$sequence)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)